# Issues with using a negative margin in background images to display bullets (IE6 and 7)

Tags: css, css-float, background-image, internet-explorer-6, margin

The subject here is the use of negative margins in bulleted lists to display an image in the gutter to the left of a title element: I found a Simplebits [article](http://simplebits.com/notebook/2005/05/23/negative/) which explains why this is a good solution for headings (it's normally used to shift columns around which doesn't have  the same consequences at all): the comments in the article are worth looking at also, as they refer to the IE issue that this causes—though no solution is offered.

In its original form, the style uses data URLs (which IE6/7 don't support at all), so I'm applying two styles concurrently, one for modern browsers, the other targeted just at IE6/7, using the `lt-ie8` [class](http://i.via.dj/ETbC):

**1. CSS for modern browsers**

```
/* IE6/7 dont display the data URL. In modern browsers this works fine. */

.linked-list-item {
    background: url(data:image/png;base64,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) no-repeat 0 4px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    margin-left: -25px
}
```

This is what the code displays (it displays the image in the margin—**note the 26px top margin for the 'Recently tweeted' heading beneath it**):

[image: The standard code for modern browsers displays correctly]

**2. CSS for IE6/7 only**

```
/*   1.   IE6 clips this if you don't add 'float:left' and 'position:relative'
 *
 *   2. { Needed to display the background
 *   3. { image in IE6 [see this thread: http://i.via.dj/EThi]. */

.lt-ie8 .linked-list-item {
    background: url(link-icon-black-16x16.jpg) no-repeat 0 2px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    margin-left: -25px;   /* 1. */
    float: left;   /* 2. */
    position: relative   /* 3. */
}
```

This displays the bullet image (**after the addition of `float: left`and `position: relative`**), but **the margin for the h2 heading has slid right up to overlap with the bulleted title**:

[image: The float in the IE style causes elements to overlap]

The first set of code (for modern browsers) works well although I do wonder whether using such a large data URL is actually worth it to avoid the extra http request—but that's not the issue here.

In its original form (without the addition of `float: left`and `position: relative`), the IE-specific markup doesn't work: IE6 clips the part of the element that's inside the negative margin, meaning it won't display the image bullet it's meant to display.

This Stack Overflow [thread](http://i.via.dj/EThi) actually suggests floating the element that's being clipped left and adding `position: relative`.

You can see the HTML and CSS, with the above code for IE only, in action in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/astorg/svNZv/).  You can also see a sandbox site in action at this [link](http://i.via.dj/EV1L): try it out in IE6 and 7 and you'll see the issues below.

**1. In IE7, the margin for the element below has collapsed and overlaps with the bulleted element's, but it's even worse, as the browser seems to be confused as to the width of the bulleted heading:**

[image: The result in IE6]

**2. In IE6 it's slightly better, though the margin has slid up also:**

[image: The result in IE6]

I'm reluctant to address this with additional markup as that would really be overkill to solve an IE6/7 only issue affecting CSS styling that's targeted only a very few visitors (as it is I'm going to quite a bit of trouble here to cater for the poor people who use those browsers…)

Still, any and all combinations I could think of with `overflow`, `clear`, `display` etc. have just not worked, and googling the issue mostly brings up issues with columns, which aren't really the same at all.

Any suggestions welcome, as always.

Comment: I don't mean to question you but... why in the world are you still supporting a browser with less that 1% market share? http://windowsteamblog.com/ie/b/ie/archive/2012/01/03/the-us-says-goodbye-to-ie6.aspx

Comment: @ChrisSobolewski: Good point—I guess I just enjoy the challenge.  It's intellectually satisfying to know you've got it to work.  Plus in this case the real issue isn't IE6 specific (since that was the clipping of the margin, which can be solved), but the float sliding up, which affects both IE6 and IE7...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I *found* the solution—use `left`instead of `margin-left` (still with a negative value, of course…  This removes the need to float the bulletted element, solving the collapsing margin issue.

Here's the fixed CSS:

```
.linked-list-item {
    background: url(http://cdn.donaldjenkins.com/media/icons/bullets/link-icon-black-16x16.jpg) no-repeat 0 2px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    left: -25px; /* IE6/7 position the element wrongly if you don't add 'position:relative' */
    position: relative;
}
```

**And this is what it results in for IE6:**

[image: The fix in IE6]

**IE7 looks the same:**

[image: The fix in IE7]

As you can see, the 26px margin for the element below the bulleted heading has reappeared.  Anyone who doesn't want to go to the same extremes as me and doesn't need data URLs can actually use this code everywhere—it works in modern browsers too.

---

**Edit February 26, 2012: Running a data-url based bullet style for modern browsers side by side with the above code, as I did on [my site](http://donaldjenkins.com/), required me to add the following two attributes to the above code, so that I have two sets of code running in parallel:**

```
<!-- 1. Modern browsers -->

.linked-list-item {
    background:url(data:image/png;base64[…morecode]) no-repeat 0 4px;
    padding-left:25px;
    margin-left:-25px
}

<!-- 2. Targets IE6/7 only -->

.lt-ie8 .linked-list-item {
    background: url(http://cdn.donaldjenkins.com/media/icons/bullets/link-icon-black-16x16.jpg) no-repeat 0 2px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    left: -25px; /* IE6/7 position the element wrongly if you don't add 'position:relative' */
    position: relative;

<!-- a. Ensures background image is always visible in IE6 -->
    height: 100%;

<!-- b. Offsets the -25px negative margin in the modern browsers code -->
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When coding css for old explorers, when you write `float:whatever`, immediately add a `display:inline` too, it fixes some margin problems. I don't know however, if this helps your concrete problem.

You can prevent margin collapsing by using an 1 pixel top/bottom padding/white border.

Maybe you could play with block formatting contexts:

```
overflow: hidden;
zoom: 1;
position: relative;
```

Shouldn't `h2.sidebar-title` have `clear: both` to disable the interference with `h2.linked-list-item`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Yeah, sorry, I forgot to list it, but I did try that in this instance and unfortunately it didn't help.

Comment: Interesting edit.  What code would you apply to get the 1-pixel top/bottom padding/white border?  There's already 25px of `padding-left` to offset the gutter created by the negative margin… (Adding `overflow: hidden` and `zoom: 1` doesn't solve it I'm afraid: http://i.via.dj/EUe9)